# byebug: Don't confirm on quit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, byebug

Is there a way to configure [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) so that it does **not** ask to confirm before exiting when issuing a `quit` command ?

```
(byebug) quit
Really quit? (y/n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [guide](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/GUIDE.md):

> If you want to quit without being prompted, suffix the command with an
>   exclamation mark, e.g., q!.